# Proof: if $a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}$ and $(a,b,c)=1$, then $c$ is odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I have attempted using proof by contradiction, however, I keep getting lost in the details with my third case. I believe I need to use $ \bmod 4 $ but I'm not sure if it's okay. I'd appreciate pointers or how to improve the proof (thank you):

***Proof:***

Let $a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2}$ and $(a, b, c) = 1$. Suppose that $c$ is even and consider the following cases:

**Case 1**: Let $a$ and $b$ be even. Then $a^{2} + b^{2}$ being even $\Rightarrow c^{2}$ is also even. However, this is a contradiction since $(a, b, c) = 1$.

**Case 2**: Without loss of generality let $a$ be even and $b$ be odd. Then $a^{2} + b^{2}$ being odd $\Rightarrow c^{2}$ is also odd. However, this is a contradiction since $c = 2k \Rightarrow c^{2}$ is even.

**Case 3**: Let $a$ and $b$ be odd. $a^{2} + b^{2} = (2k + 1)^{2} + (2l + 1)^{2} \equiv 2 \bmod 4$. However, this is a contradiction since $c^{2} \equiv 0 \bmod 4$.

Thus, by contradiction, if $a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2}$ and $(a, b, c) = 1$ then $c$ is odd. QED.

Comment: Looks OK. I think you can use the same cases without first assuming $c$ is even, and - much as you already have - find contradictions to other conditions in two cases and that $c$ is odd in case 2.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $c$ is even, then $a$ and $b$ are both odd or both even, being both even gives $(a,b,c)>1$

if $a^2$ and $b^2$ are odd then $a^2\equiv b^2\equiv 1\bmod 4$ and so $c^2\equiv 2\bmod 4$ and thus is not a square. So $c$ cannot be even.

Answer (score 0):

$$
c \equiv_2 0 \Rightarrow c^2 \equiv_4 0 \Rightarrow a^2 + b^2 \equiv_4 0 \Rightarrow a \equiv_2 0 \land b \equiv_2 0 \Rightarrow 2|(a,b,c)
$$
contradictio