# Prove by contradiction that if $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $a^2 +b^2 =c^2$, then at least one of the numbers $a,b$ is odd.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, pythagorean-triples

Here is what I have done so far.

We assume that both $a$ and $b$ are even. Then $\exists \kappa,\lambda\in\mathbb{N}_0$ such that $a=2\kappa$ and $b=2\lambda$. Then,

$a^2+b^2=c^2\Leftrightarrow (2\kappa)^2+(2\lambda)^2=c^2\Leftrightarrow c=2\sqrt{{\kappa}^2+{\lambda}^2} $

I am not sure if that helps though, and if it leads to a contradiction. So, any ideas how I should procceed?

Comment: But $6^2+8^2=10^2$. However, at least one of $a,b$ must be even.

Comment: See http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pythagtriple.pdf

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184589/

Comment: @P.D.: Is my answer fine, or could it be improved? I was not sure if this is the kind of answer you expected.

Comment: @Watson : I am not sure how the fact that $c$ is even contradicts our assumption cause we haven't assumed anywhere that $c$ is odd. Does this happen because if at least one of $a,b$ is odd then we have two cases: both odd or one even and one odd, where in both cases this leads to an odd number, and hence a contradiction?

Comment: In my answer the assumption is a reference to "if you assume that $a,b,c$ have no common divisor." Otherwise the claim is wrong as shown by Arthur's example.

Comment: you forgot to say that a,b,c were coprimes , as usual with this exercise

Comment: Q is not properly posed.  Must specify that $gcd(a,b,c)=1$; if q is edited I remove the downvote.

Comment: There is nothing mentioned about a,b,c being coprime in this exercise! That's the reason why it confused me. I haven't construct this question by myself. So I guess that the question is not correctly specified.

Comment: Are you sure that the question is not asking "at least one of $a,b$ must be even." ?

Comment: The question is asking exactly that. To prove that at least one of $a,b$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. As noted by Arthur, you have $6^2+8^2=10^2$. However, this becomes true if you assume that $a,b,c$ have no common divisor.

Indeed, your equation $(2\kappa)^2+(2\lambda)^2=c^2$ would mean that $c^2$ is a multiple of $4$, hence $c$ would be even. As $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be even, this would contradict our assumption.

Comment: if the question is reducible to being trivial, you should try to understand it in its most general form before posting your answer so both you and other users can learn more.

Comment: @DeepSea: So I'm not answering the question correctly? What would be the "most general form", according to you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the problem isn't really a problem, as it can be reduced to a case when it doesn't apply and a case when it is trivial.

It is possible (but not necessary) for both a and b to be even when a and b share common factors, like in the above example of (a, b, c) = (6, 8, 10). Specifically, if and only if c is even, both a and b must be even, as this is the only way for c^2 to have the correct modulo 4.

When there are no common factors, then exactly one of a and b must be odd, but this is trivial. The statement of 'no common factors' automatically excludes pairs of even numbers sharing the factor 2, so it's a trivial correlation.